# Tomcat 7: how to log x509 cert dn with AccessLogValve

Tags: logging, tomcat, x509

I have Tomcat7 running on RHEL6 with mutual authentication using x509 certificates for the entire container.

From the user point of view in the browser, everything seems to work fine with a cert challenge.  This is on an intranet with a proxy.

My goal is have the user x509 cert dn written out to the AccessLogValve logs.

Following [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/624790/tomcat-log-the-equivalent-of-ssl-client-s-dn) post I have modified the AccessLogValve pattern (in server.xml) to include:

```
%{javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate}r
```

However what is written to the logs are strings like this:

```
[Ljava.security.cert.X509Certicate;@4737f9e8
```

My concern is that the cert-related headers are being dropped, so I have also enabled the RequestDumperFilter in web.xml to look for clues in the headers.  In those logs I don't see anything cert-related other than possibly:

```
remoteUser=null 
isSecure=true 
=============
authType=null
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this without creating a cutom valve?